# Send email to multiple user with same content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I've got a working mailer which sends email to users, however when I changed it a bit, it seems that everything is not so great.

I'm trying to send email with the same content to different user, but wanting each mail to have have "hi user.firstname" as a greet.

This is my mailer relevant :

```
  def notify_users(requestor, user)
    [requestor, user].each{ |u| notify_user(u, requestor) }  
  end

  def notify_user(user, requestor)
    @user = user
    @requestor = requestor
    mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Change requested by user"
  end
```

This is my template named 'notify_user.text.haml':

```
= "Hi #{@user.firstname},"
\
= "The user #{@requestor.firstname} #{@requestor.lastname} has suggested that he has completed his work"
```

This result in mail being sent to the user only but not to the requestor as well. The other thing that is confusing is that the email delivered is empty.

This is generated from my email client :

```
This message has no body:
No message part with HTML or TXT content type
```

Does anybody have some hints or suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid

Comment: I'm already using mailtrap.io

Comment: you use `ActionMailer`?

Comment: @Monk_Code yes I do use ActionMailer

Comment: i think you need use `html.erb` because render support only `text` and `html`.

Comment: same thing happens when I change to html.erb or html.haml

Comment: and you change code from `haml` to `erb`?

Comment: I removed the html bit left just text, so I can decrease problem complexity for now

Answer (score 0):

You can use action mailer or mandril api.

```
def notify_user(email, requestor)
   @requestor = requestor
   mail :to => email, :subject => "Change requested by user"
end
```

here email is array of all users email.

```
UserMailer.new.notify_user(email, requestor).deliver
```